# Android Studio Error:Unable to continue until an Android SDK is specified

Tags: android-studio

I just tried to install Android Studio on my Windows 10 system. When I open Android Studio it ask me where my Android SDK is.  But according to the documentation http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio

> Android Studio provides everything you need to start developing apps
>   for Android, including the Android Studio IDE and the Android SDK
>   tools.

So what's gives? I guess Android Studio does NOT provide everything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that it does *not provide everything* as stated in the documentation elsewhere. The link at the bottom of the page that you reference is here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

And it states:

> **Adding SDK Packages**
>
> By default, the Android SDK does not include
>   everything you need to start developing. The SDK separates tools,
>   platforms, and other components into packages you can download as
>   needed using the Android SDK Manager. So before you can start, there
>   are a few packages you should add to your Android SDK.

In other words, the SDK itself comes kind of "empty" and you need to define how you will use it by adding the components/tools/platform versions/etc. that you will need for developing your particular app. To include all of this would severely bloat the download and installation.

Comment: Still no solution how to get my Andriod SDK. It seems I have a chicken and egg problem: Everywhere I read I can update the SDK tools. But nowhere it is explained how I get an SDK Location in the first place. The link in Android Studio 2023.1.1 only leads to a general Android Studio page. [Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk) it is explained how to 'install' the SDK. But I need an SDK Location first. And for that I need to have an SDK installed... :-S

Comment: I created a ~/Android/Sdk directory. Then in the SDK Manager I edited the Android SDK Location. I used the pre-selected SDK in the list, pressed Next, Next, Finish and now I am up and running. `:-)

Answer (score 1):

Open a new terminal (**WIN + R**, type `cmd` and press **ENTER**) > type `adb --version`

Then, the **PATH** of your `platform-tools` will be displayed in the terminal under the line `Installed as`. Copy the **PATH** (ex: `D:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe`) and in Android Studio go to: Tools > SDK manager > Edit "Android SDK Location" > Paste the new location > Click on Apply/OK buttons > Restart Android Studio.

Comment: Unfortunatly solution not possible: "The Android SDK lcoation cannot be at the filesystem root." :-(

Comment: I created a ~/Android/Sdk directory. Then in the SDK Manager I edited the Android SDK Location. I used the pre-selected SDK in the list, pressed Next, Next, Finish and now I am up and running. `:-)

Answer (score -2):

What I have realized by android studio sdk is , it can not be installed where by folders have spaces like user/monna motho/appdata/src the space between monna and motho will make installation for sdk to be skipped automatically

Comment: You can use spaces in address of SDK, it will give you warning but it will allow you to use it. and Android will suggest not to use as it could lead to unexpected behaviors.